# XSLT: Problem with the <xsl:choose> element

Tags: xml, xslt

I've recently started to work with XML and XSLT and I've encountered a problem that I'm having trouble solving.

I have a project in which I need to create an XSLT that works with 3 different objects in XML.

The objects are expositions.

Full XML (sorry it's not in English, it's quite big to translate and for the sake of keeping the elements name equal I'll keep it as the original version):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="exposição.xsl"?>
<museu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="exp.xsd">
    <exposicoes>
        <presente titulo="Exposições Atuais">
            
          <!-- Exposition_A-->  
            <exposicao titulo="Vamos dar vida à Sala Patiño">  
                <imagem ficheiro="http://museudearteantiga.pt/content/img/sala_patino.jpg" width="600" height="350"/>
                <descricao>
                    <objetivo>Restauro da Sala</objetivo>
                    <texto titulo="Apresentação do Projeto">
                     ...
                     </texto>   
                </descricao>
                <!--Caracteristics_A-->
                <dados_exp>
                    <caracteristicas nome="Sala Palatiño">
                        <estilo>Artes Decorativas Francesas</estilo>
                        <inauguração data="ano">1974</inauguração>
                        <doador> Antenor Patiño</doador>
                        <data_criação data="ano">1769</data_criação>
                        <criador>J. G. Leithner</criador>
                        <inspiração>Palácio de Paar</inspiração>
                        <arquiteto>Isidore Canevale</arquiteto>
                        <objetos>
                            <objeto>Conjunto de móveis de assento |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Guarnição de chaminé |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Tapete |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Lustre |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Relógio de parede |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Par de cómodas |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Vasos de Saxe</objeto>
                        </objetos>    
                    </caracteristicas>
                </dados_exp>
                <inf_adicionais>
                <data>
                    <inicio>
                        <dia>30</dia>
                        <mes>10</mes>
                        <ano>2018</ano>
                    </inicio>
                    <fim>
                        <dia>31</dia>
                        <mes>12</mes>
                        <ano>2020</ano>
                    </fim>
                </data>
                <local>
                    <piso>1</piso>
                    <sala>66</sala>
                </local>
                <doacao>    
                  <pagamento modalidade="dinheiro"> Museu Nacional de Arte Antiga (caixas do GAMNAA)</pagamento>
                  <pagamento modalidade="transferência bancária">Grupo dos Amigos do Museu Nacional de Arte Antiga
                      <iban>PT50 0036 0458 99106001472 91</iban>
                      <BIC_SWIFT>MPIOPTPL</BIC_SWIFT>
                  </pagamento>
                    <contacto>
                        <email>geral@mnaa.dgpc.pt</email>
                        <dados_necessarios>nome, morada, NIF e enviar comprovativo da comparticipação</dados_necessarios>
                    </contacto>
                    <nota>todos os doadores serão considerados anónimos, exceto aqueles que expressarem a vontade de serem identificados, apresentando comprovativo da comparticipação.</nota>
                </doacao>
             </inf_adicionais>
            </exposicao>
            
            
           <!--Exposition_B--> 
            <exposicao titulo="Todos Somos Mecenas">  
                <imagem ficheiro="http://museudearteantiga.pt/content/img/expo_capela.jpg" width="600" height="350"/>
                <descricao>
                    <objetivo>Restauro da Convento de Santo Alberto</objetivo>
                    <texto titulo="Apresentação do Projeto">
                       ...
                    </texto> 
                </descricao>
                <!--Caracteristics_B-->
                <dados_exp>
                    <caracteristicas nome="Convento Santo Alberto" nome_popular="Capela das Albertas">
                        <estilo>Barroco Português</estilo>
                        <inauguração data="ano">1585</inauguração>
                        <data_criação data="ano"></data_criação>
                        <ordem_religiosa>Ordem das Camelitas</ordem_religiosa>
                        <objetos>        
                            <objeto>Talha dourada |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Azulejos</objeto>
                        </objetos>
                        <destaques>
                            Sumptuoso interior Arquitetura Pintura Escultura Artes Decorativas
                        </destaques>        
                    </caracteristicas>
                </dados_exp>
                <inf_adicionais>
                    <data>
                        <inicio>
                            <dia>01</dia>
                            <mes>12</mes>
                            <ano>2018</ano>
                        </inicio>
                        <fim>
                            <dia>31</dia>
                            <mes>12</mes>
                            <ano>2020</ano>
                        </fim>
                    </data>
                    <local>
                        <piso>1/Capela das Albertas</piso>
                    </local>
                    <doacao>    
                        <pagamento modalidade="dinheiro"> Museu Nacional de Arte Antiga (caixas do GAMNAA)</pagamento>
                        <pagamento modalidade="transferência bancária">Grupo dos Amigos do Museu Nacional de Arte Antiga
                            <iban>PT50 0036 0458 99106001472 91</iban>
                            <BIC_SWIFT>MPIOPTPL</BIC_SWIFT>
                        </pagamento>
                        <contacto>
                            <email>geral@mnaa.dgpc.pt</email>
                            <dados_necessarios>nome, morada, NIF e enviar comprovativo da comparticipação</dados_necessarios>
                        </contacto>
                        <nota>todos os doadores serão considerados anónimos, exceto aqueles que expressarem a vontade de serem identificados,
                            apresentando comprovativo da comparticipação.</nota>
                    </doacao>
                </inf_adicionais>
            </exposicao>
            
            
            
            <!--Exposition-C-->
            <exposicao titulo="Estudo, Conservação e Restauro dos Painéis de São Vicente">
                <imagem ficheiro="http://museudearteantiga.pt/content/img/paineis_800x450.jpg" width="600" height="350"/>
                <descricao>
                    <objetivo>Conservação e restauro dos painéis</objetivo>
                    <texto titulo="Apresentação do Projeto">
                        ...
                    </texto>                      
                </descricao>
                
                <!--Caracteristics_C-->
                <dados_exp>
                    <caracteristicas nome="Paineis de São Vicente">
                        <estilo>Realista</estilo>
                        <inauguração data="ano">2020</inauguração>
                        <data_criação data="século">XV</data_criação>
                        <objetos>
                            <objeto>Painel dos Frades |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Painel dos Pescadores |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Painel do Infante |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Painel do Arcebispo |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Painel dos Cavaleiros |</objeto>
                            <objeto>Painel da Relíquia </objeto>
                        </objetos>
                    </caracteristicas>
                </dados_exp>
                <inf_adicionais>
                    <data>
                        <inicio>
                            <dia>01</dia>
                            <mes>06</mes>
                            <ano>2020</ano>
                        </inicio>
                        <fim>
                            <dia>18</dia>
                            <mes>05</mes>
                            <ano>2022</ano>
                        </fim>
                    </data>
                    <local>
                        <piso>3</piso>
                    </local>
                    <mecenas nome="Fundação Millennium BCP">
                        <imagem ficheiro="logo_fundação_millennium_bcp.jpg" width= "200" height= "135" />            
                        <texto titulo="Sobre a  Fundação Millennium bcp">
                           ...
                        </texto>
                    </mecenas>
                </inf_adicionais>
            </exposicao>
        </presente>
    </exposicoes>
</museu>
```

And here is those elements in the XSLT (updated):

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl: stylesheet xmlns: xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns: xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes = "xs"
    version = "2.0">
  <xsl: output method = "html" />
  <xsl: template match = "/">
    <xsl: for-each select = "/ museum / exposition / present / exposition">
    <xsl: result-document method = "html" href = "exposition _ {@ title} .html">
       
  <html>
   <head>
    <title> National Museum of Ancient Art </title>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text / css" href = "201906497.css" />
     <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />
     <script src = "https://kit.fontawesome.com/802bcd581f.js" crossorigin = "anonymous"> </script>
   </head>
        
   <body>
     <div class = "header">
                ...
       <div class = "navbar">
            ...
       </div>
         <! - Exhibition ->
        <div class = "secheader">
         <h1 class = "title2" id = "tbpag3"> <xsl: value-of select = "@ title" /> </h1>
       </div>
        <! - End of Header ->
            
       <div class = "data_exp">
       <div class = "img_sp">
         <img src = "{image / @ file}" width = "600" height = "350" />
       </div>
       <div class = "box1">
         <p> <strong> Objective | </strong> <xsl: value-of select = "description / objective" /> </p>
         <p class = "exp1">
            <xsl: value-of select = "description / text" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
               
            <div class="dados_exp">
                <h3>Dados da Exposição</h3>
                
               
                <p><strong> Estilo| </strong>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(estilo) = ''"> Informação Indisponível
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/estilo"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose></p>
                
                
                <p><strong>Inauguração|</strong>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(inauguração)=''"> Informação Indisponível
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/inauguração"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>   
                </xsl:choose></p>
                
                
                
                <p><strong> Doador| </strong>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(doador)=''"> Informação Indisponível    
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/doador"/> 
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                 </xsl:choose></p>
                
                
                
                <p><strong> Data de Criação| </strong>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(data_criação)=''"> Informação Indisponível  
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/data_criação"/> 
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose></p>
                    
                
                
                
                <p><strong> Autor| </strong>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(criador)=''"> Informação Indisponível   
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/criador"/> 
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose></p>
                
                
                
                <p><strong> Inspiração| </strong>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(inspiração)=''"> Informação Indisponível    
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/inspiração"/> 
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose></p>
                   
                    
                
                <p><strong> Arquiteto| </strong>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(arquiteto)=''"> Informação Indisponível 
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/arquiteto"/> 
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose></p>
                
                
                
                <p><strong> Ordem Religiosa| </strong>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(ordem_religiosa)=''"> Informação Indisponível   
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/ordem_religiosa"/> 
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose></p>
                
                
                
                <p><strong> Objetos| </strong>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(objeto)=''"> Informação Indisponível    
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/objetos/objeto"/> 
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose></p>
                
             </div>
            
            ...
            
    </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My objective would be either for these elements to disappear when they don't exist in an exposition or to show the text "Information Unavailable" in front of the element of the HTML in the XSLT.
I've tried this way but all it leaves is the HTML part with nothing in front.
I would very much appreciate all the help you might be able to provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

The below may work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select = "museu/exposicoes/presente/exposicao">
        <!-- here you may select all info beneath exposicao node -->
        <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="@titulo"/>
        </title>
            
            <p>
                <strong> Style | </strong>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(dados_exp/caracteristicas/estilo) = ''"> Information Unavailable </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="dados_exp/caracteristicas/estilo"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think it would be better if you copy your entire XSL. Maybe what I did below may help you.

XML:

```
<characteristics name = "exp_C">
  <style> Realistic </style>
  <inauguration> 2020 </inauguration>
  <creation_data> XV </creation_data>
  <creator> Nuno Gonçalves </creator>
  <objects>
    <object> Panel of the Friars | </object>
    <object> Fishermen's Panel | </object>
    <object> Infante's Panel | </object>
    <object> Archbishop's Panel | </object>
    <object> Panel of the Knights | </object>
    <object> Relic Panel | </object>
  </objects>
</characteristics>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="characteristics">
        <p>
            <strong> Style | </strong>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test = "normalize-space(style) = ''"> Information Unavailable </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="style"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<p><strong> Style | </strong> Realistic </p>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your insight. As you advised I have updated the XSLT, so it has as much information as I believe it's necessary. I apologize if the code I supplied before wasn't enough to understand how my XSLT was formulated.

Comment: Regarding the solution you provided, I've tried to update my code but unfortunately, the problem still persists (the "Information Unavailable" text does not appear when an element doesn't exist in a certain exposition e.g. in the case of exposition B, where the element "donor" does not exist, giving me this result in the output: Donor |         , leaving the space where it should be "Information Unavailable" empty).

Comment: Maybe that's because the node isn't completely empty. If you have whitespace in there, that's not empty. I edited the answer adding normalize-space function on the when-test clause. Let me know if this works. If it doesn't work, make sure that your template is matching "characteristics" at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your help once again. Adding the normalize-space function adds the text "Information Unavailable" in the output. However, it appears in every case, even when the elements are not empty (where it should appear the text defined in the XML).

Comment: Could you also copy your entire XML? I think the reason is on your "for-each". It is making a for each "/ museum / exposition / present / exposition". The XMLs you posted before have characteristics. Maybe you should add a new for-each or add characteristics on your current for-each.

Comment: I've updated the XML and it is now available the complete version, although not in English due to the size of the code and the importance of keeping the elements name equal. Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: Great, not a problem, I am from Brazil as well, haha. I updated the XSL. Your path was not correctly to test the style. Your for-each is being done on "exposicao". To reach "estilo", you may go to "dados_exp/caracteristicas" before. Then you can test "estilo". Let me know if this works.